# How to update a table column data, containing ( ' ) symble in data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am getting error in microsoft sql server because the data I want to update is contains (') symbol in the data.

```
update Employee_table
set
brokername='Angie's Broker',
where ID=7788;
```

Please someome resolve the problem.

Comment: use double `'` to escape `'Angie''s Broker',`

Comment: Ideally you would use parameterized queries where this is not an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For single quotes used inside a string literal, you put another single quote before it. This is called "escaping" the single quote, and different sorts of escaping are quite usual in programming:

```
update Employee_table
set
brokername='Angie''s Broker',
where ID=7788;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   UPDATE Employee_table SET brokername = 'Angie''s Broker' WHERE id = 7788;
```

To update a table column that contains the single quote symbol ('), you can use the escape sequence ('') to represent the single quote in the data.

Comment: How does this differ to the other answer?

Comment: There is no wrong comma before  `where`

Comment: Wow, this should be a reason to create a new answer? Why not just commenting the other one to hint that?

Answer (score 0):

Another way to escape the single quote is to use the unicode char like below :

```
update Employee_table
set brokername='Angie' + CHAR(39) + 's Broker',
where ID=7788;
```